# Extract image ROI with a rotated rectangle

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm facing a problem with extracting not-straight ROIs.
Until now, I have the following:

```
cv::RotatedRect face_rotated_roi(rotated_center, face_roi.size(), rotation_angle);
cv::Mat face = cv::Mat(oriented_face, face_rotated_roi.boundingRect());
```

but if the ratio of width/height differs from 1 (it isn't a square), the boundingRect gives me a bigger ROI.

Is there any way to extract **exactly** the ROI delimited by my RotatedRect?

Comment: Seems the same problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279853/how-to-store-all-the-pixels-within-a-rotatedrect-to-another-matrix/26284491#26284491

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Andrey Smodorov, I fixed the problem thanks to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279853/how-to-store-all-the-pixels-within-a-rotatedrect-to-another-matrix/26284491#26284491).

It was the same problem, but in my case I had first to find the rotation (in case the face is laying down) and then construct the rotated rectangle and apply the proposed solution.